# Elevate python subpackage with importlib

Tags: python

I have a package with subpackages. When importing package I want to dynamically make one of the subpackages available as a fixed name. How do I do this?

```
/package
    __init__.py
    /subpackage1
        __init__.py
    /subpackage2
        __init__.py
```

From the outside I would like to be able to do `from package import subpackage`, and the `__init__.py` in package makes the correct subpackage (1 or 2) available as package.subpackage depending on an environment variable.

edit: I specifically want to use `importlib.import_module()` to do this, because I need to put together a string that gives the path to the subpackage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to import the correct subpackage in `package/__init__.py` as `subpackage`.

```
import importlib
import os

if os.environ.get('MY_ENV_VAR', None):  # Check your env condition here
    pkg = '.subpackage1'
else:
    pkg = '.subpackage2'
subpackage = importlib.import_module(pkg, __name__)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is correct. I was not clear enough in my question: I specifically want to use importlib to do this, because I need to put together the correct path for the import and I don't want to have a lot of if/else conditions.

Comment: @Maltimore Ah, I see. I've changed the answer, check out if it works for you now.